# setServerCertificate() function is not in Cobalt EME API in 'drm.h'

Tags: cobalt

Does the latest code of 'drm.h' in master branch meet the EME part of 2018 YouTube TV HTML5 Technical Requirements?

Widevine CE CDM stongly recommands to use the certificate from servers, and we met with some problems using the old method with latest CDM library.

How can we always get certificate from Youtube with Cobalt?

Answer (score 0):

Can you report this to the Cobalt issue tracker?
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:181120

Comment: Thanks for your review. I have put it on issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks! Cobalt team will check the issue and provide you feedback.

Comment: @CeriRuan, I responded in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62116654.